# How pop() work inside this if condition statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In the code below

```js
function validBraces(braces) {
  var matches = { '(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']' };
  var stack = [];
  var currentChar;

  for (var i = 0; i < braces.length; i++) {
    currentChar = braces[i];
    if (matches[currentChar]) {
      stack.push(currentChar);
    } else {
      if (currentChar !== matches[stack.pop()]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return stack.length === 0;
}
```

To my understanding, this code

> currentChar !== matches[stack.pop()]

check that current char is the necessary opening braces of last element in the stack array and if it is correct it pop the last element in stack array. but in the syntax, there is no condition if it matches, like this

```
if(currentChar == matches[stack.pop()]
{stack.pop()}
```

So, is `stack.pop()` working inside the if condition statement despite there is no true condition for it. How exactly is it working here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is evaluated from inside out.

[`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from the array and returns the removed value. And this character (because `stack` contains only characters) is used to access the respective property in the `matches` object.

You can rewrite the code as follows:

```
if (currentChar !== matches[stack.pop()]) {
  return false;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
let stackElement = stack.pop();
let match = matches[stackElement];
if (currentChar !== match) {
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT** regarding your comment

No returning true  from this position in the code doesn't have anything to do with the "characteristic" of `pop` (whatever you mean by that).

The whole function is a check for balanced braces. And that specific part of the code checks, whether the current char is the matching equivalent of the current element on the stack. If that's not the case, the braces are not correctly matched, thus you can immediately return `false`. But you cannot return `true` at this position, because to be able to determine, that the braces are correctly matched, you have to examine the whole input string. Thus, the last line of the function

```
return stack.length === 0;
```

where you check, *after the whole string as been handled*, if all braces have been correctly matched. If `stack.length === 0` gives false, there are still unmatched braces on the stack, thus the result of the function is `false`. If `stack.length === 0` gives true, there is no unmatched brace left, thus the result of the function is `true`

Comment: so 1. stack.pop is excuted ( remove the last element and take it) 
2. check it is correct 3. if it is false, return false and end the loop.No statement for true is needed because it is already executed like this you mean. is it the characteristic of pop() only? does any other methods has this characteristic

Comment: Thanks, it is pretty clear now, appreicate for the time and efforts. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

stack.pop() is executed before evaluation of the expression. It would be identical to the following code:

```js
// ...

const lastEncounteredOpeningBracket = stack.pop();
const requiredClosingBracket = matches[lastEncounteredOpeningBracket]

if (currentChar !== requiredClosingBracket ) {
  return false;
}

// ...
```